# Which IRT model is recommended to capture manifest continuous indicators (items)?

Tags: continuous-data, item-response-theory

The test under investigation comprises of continuous items, whose response space is not limited to a special interval (such as [0;1]). Instead, my items are developed for measuring the execution speed of movements over a given time interval held constant for every item. My question are:

1. whether there are IRT models for capturing such test situations (next to factor analysis),
2. if there are model extensions for classification needs (such as the case for the mixed rasch model, for instancE)
3. whether there are software solutions (practically in R)

Thanks in advance for every idea and comment!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the nature of your data, but yes there are items beyond dichotomous and polytomous IRT models to handle outcomes with continuous nature.

- You refer 'execution speed of movements', so if this is time outcome, you may use the [Lognormal Response Time model.](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.3102/10769986031002181)  There is an [R package] (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LNIRT/LNIRT.pdf) you can use.
- There is also Continuous IRT Model. [This blog post](https://cengiz.me/posts/crm-stan/) introduces three different ways of fitting the model in R.
- If you want to treat the outcome as count, this paper may give you an idea.
  https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0013164418824148